# Azure Cognitive Search: Debug session throws "session status" error

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Trying to start a debug session to experiment with adding a custom skill. When I hit run, this message appears:

```
Session status: Running
Debug session is running. Please wait a few seconds for the latest data.
```

But then is almost immediately replaced with:

```
Session status: Error
Parsing failure: unexpected ' '; expected end of input (Line 1, Column 16); recently consumed: ment/Start
```

The Indexer, Skillset, Datasource, and Index objects attached to the debug session all work just fine on their own. I only experience issues from within the debug session. The "Errors/Warnings" tab continues to report "No errors or warnings", even after repeatedly attempting to run the skillset through the debug session and getting that same error.

Comment: Hi David. Would it be possible to share your skillset definition?

Comment: I suspect this might be an issue with one of the "targetName"s defined in the skillset. Does any of the target name contain non-alphanumeric characters?